# Need help to understand why something tips over and how to prevent it

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am designing a television stand for 55 inch television that weighs 24 kilograms. Now, i have made a stand and attached it to the back of the television. Now, what should be the weight of the stand to prevent the tv from tipping. And is a straight rectangular design that stands behind the tv can be stable, or do i need to extend it to the front of the tv. And also, another question - When designing any new product how can i be sure that the product will be stable and not tip over. Please explain as you would to a high school student, because i am not good at physics. Please see the attached image.

[image: tv stand]

Comment: This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

The main discipline that studies this tip over phenomena is "statics".

In simple terms, for stability, the center of gravity of an object must lie in between its touch down points.

One more thing is, if someone tilts the TV, or if you put it on an inclined place, the weight vector must still be inside the touch down points (base) of the tv. Else, it will  fall on its own.

For these inclined or dynamic situations, the lower the CG, the better the stability of an object.